# How to archive old data in PostgreSQL without using Partition or cloning table

Tags: postgresql

I have table it has more than 2GB data so I wanted to archive previous year old and kept in DB because it is effecting my application and DB performance.

Comment: So you Copy the data to the archive table and delete it from the source table not playing?

Comment: Did you already have a good look at why your queries are slow? If your queries are constantly doing table scans because of filter conditions on non indexed columns defining the right indexes might solve your problem too.

Comment: I added indexing for tables but it not solved issues. I have two tables linked if i making changes in table constraint or any new column that time if I updating my module I am getting Java heap space error because object was keep on checking table data.

Comment: I tried to take only data backup of that table and truncated table data after that My release was  successful so I am looking archive of previous year table so with truncating i can release modules in my application

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a backup table with a different tablespace to archive your old data.

If you don't want to create a backup clone table, then you can take an export dump of your table using pg_dump utility. Note that to access the data you will have to import that dump into the database.

Comment: I tried to take only data backup of that table and truncated table data after that My release was successful so I am looking archive of previous year table so with truncating i can release modules in my application